# Colors appearing differently on website vs design software

Tags: html, css, colors, adobe-xd

I have been designing my own website for a little while now, and I have noticed that the colors that appear on the live version of the website are different from the colors I am using within my design software (Adobe XD).

I am using hex codes to represent the colors, and despite being the same hex code, the colors appear differently.

Here is a screenshot displaying the difference between the two colors:

[image]

While you can see that the color codes are identical:
[image]

Why is this the case? Is it possible to get it to be the correct color, or is this just something to do with how the web displays colors?

Comment: This seems to be a known issue with XD. The web uses sRGB color space while XD uses the devies raw color space. Even colors in PS compared to XD look different. See here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2257773

Comment: It's insane that Adobe has not fixed this in 3 years. Doesn't even need to be a complicated colorspace management system. Just make your software that's for designing for the web match the sRGB colorspace of the browsers that 99% of people use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hex codes are **not universal numbers**, meaning that a hex code alone doesn't mean anything unless a color space is specified. The differences in the colors are due to your design software using a different color space than the browser you're using to display the website. For more information you should check out [this similar thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2009937) on hex codes and color spaces.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification! Is it possible to match the colors to be identical outside of Adobe XD? That would make this design process much simpler going forward with the knowledge that everything is the same.

Comment: @primelf As of yet, Adobe XD doesn't allow for selecting a different color space. Almost all web browsers use sRGB, while Adobe uses their own color space called Adobe RGB, which is why your colors will almost always be inconsistent. Unfortunately, there is no way around this issue that I know of, other than the extremely lame answer of using different design software.

Answer (score 1):

Every browser displays the colors differently. Try using another browser and see by yourself. This is the way it appears on Google Chrome:
[image: Color with Chrome]

And this is the way it appears on Firefox:

[image: Color with Firefox]

What I'm trying to say is that there doesn't seem to be a solution to this problem as it's going to appear in a different way on each browser.

Comment: XD is the issue here.

Comment: But he wants his website to appear the way he designed it to be in XD. I've came across the same issue before

Comment: Yes XD's color space is messed up. Telling someone to use "another browser" is not any kind of useful answer even if that was a fix, which in this case it doenst seem to be.

Comment: Yes that's what I was trying to say. That there is no solution, as each software displays colors differently. Anyway, I edited the answer and I hope it's more clear now.